# Angular2 and RestApi at the same container

Tags: spring, angular

I'm trying to run  Angular2 WebClient and Spring Rest Api on the same container -> tomcat9.

When I run Angular2 WebClient on  Apache Server ( on the same machine) all work fine.   When I'm trying to run it at the same container as RestApi, I get an error

> Options  "some url" net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I was trying resolve this problem by adding  frameOptions policy in my Spring security configuration :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, SecurityProperties.PATH_PATTERN_ALL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(SecurityProperties.PATH_PATTERN_ROOT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(SecurityProperties.PATH_PATTERN_LOGON).authenticated()

           (...)    .and().httpBasic().realmName(SecurityProperties.REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
}
```

Comment: In general, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, means host/port couple can't be reached. Can you detail your deployment ? By container, you mean Docker one ? How are hosted each service in your container ? A single Java Web Server ?

Comment: The RESTAPI is on ROOT,  the client on  clinet directory in webapps. I use the same package  as on Apache Server. As I mentionned..   th application from apache server connect  correctly to RestApi

Comment: Have you checked that URLs called by your Angular2 application are correct ?

Comment: yes.   The same package deployed on apache server works fine